# Primeng checkbox checked issue angular

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng-checkbox

In my working on angular 8 application where I am using primeng checkbox and I have some issue.Checkbox data is coming from db. So if status==0, I have to make it unchecked and if status==1, it should be selected even if load the table(default). I tried many ways and its not working. Can any one please point me the issue or any suggestions will be of great help.

```js
 onStatusChange(id: number,status: number) {
        this.id = id;
        console.log('Id', id);
        console.log('Checked');
        this.status = status;
        console.log('Status', status);
        
    }
```

```html
<p-checkbox [value]="text.id" [(ngModel)]="status" binary="true"  (onChange)="onStatusChange(TextID,status)"></p-checkbox>
```

Data from db is coming like this

```html
{"Text":
[
  {"ID":"1","Name":"Text","textContent":"content1,"status":"1"},
  {"ID":"2","Name":"Text","textContent":"content1,"status":"1"},
  {"ID":"3","Name":"Text","textContent":"content1,"status":"0"}
]
}
```

Tried  ternary if statement inside inside ngModel and ngModelChange

```html
text.IsActive[text.IsActive==1?'true':'false'
```

I am getting the required data in onStatusChange to make it active or inactive for updating it to DB. But problem lies in making checkbox checked based on the selection while loading the data.
Please help me.. stuck here for the last few days..

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know is that worked for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

I this you can use `(ngModelChange)` instead of `(onChange)`. The code is given below =>

**HTML**

```
  <div>
    <p-checkbox 
      label="My CheckBox" 
      binary="true" 
      [(ngModel)]="showLinkedRisksOnly"
      (ngModelChange) ="myModelChanged($event)"
      >
    </p-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div>
    Value: {{showLinkedRisksOnly}}
    </div>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  showLinkedRisksOnly = true;
  myModelChanged($event){
    console.log($event);
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** You can check the code in [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-p-checkbox-issue-ysrjee?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks for your help .But didnot work. Status value is coming as 1 or 0 not true or false. I will add more details in my post. Please help me .. stuck here

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the status directly as a number, you can map it to `true` or `false` with `!!`

```
1 => !!1 => true
0 => !!0 => false
```

If `1` or `0` should be a string then:

```
"1" => !!Number("1") => true
"0" => !!Number("0") => false
```

this allows you to use the values in the checkbox normally